# How to check posted value already exist in db or not?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to check if posted username is exist in db with email address or not.
How to check that?

```
public function check_all($username) 
        {
            $check = $this->db->where("username","email", $username)->get("users");
            if($check->num_rows() > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you `select ... where email=$email or username=$username`, basically. since you've provided absolutely NO details as to what this `db->where` stuff is, or how it works, that's about all we can suggest.

Comment: Sorry i am using codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/ @MarcB

Comment: This certainly is possible, but does not really make too much sense. It is a more effective strategy to simply try to insert right away. That will fail if your combined index, declared as unique, already contains the combination. That is enough for you to conclude an already taken user name. This saves you the additional select statement, thus saves time and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to check if a username exist you could try the following code snippet

```
public function check_all($username) 
        {
            $results = $this->db->select('USERNAME')
                               ->from('USERS')
                               ->where('USERNAME', $username)
                               ->get();

            if($results->num_rows() > 0)
            {
              //The user exist
              return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If you're looking to check if the user has an email address you could do

```
public function check_all($username) 
        {
            $results = $this->db->select('USERNAME')
                                ->from('USERS')
                                ->where('USERNAME', $username)
                                ->where('EMAIL IS NOT NULL')
                                ->get();

            if($results->num_rows() > 0)
            {
              //The user has an email
              return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello i want to know, how to check if someone post email address as username and how to make them valid?

Comment: If user post email or username through same `$username` then how to check that is valid or exist ?

Comment: Can you provide two examples of valid values for `$username` I am assuming you mean that when the function is called you can call the function as `check_all('Mehur')` or `check_all('Mehur@place.com')` and that you would like the function to return if the user exist? If you can provide more detail in your question so we can better answer it, and provide examples.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008992/how-to-check-email-or-username-is-valid-or-exist-through-same-post

Comment: Any alternative of `EMAIL IS NOT NULL` ? I have `email` in row so should i use `->where('email')` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 approaches. Method 1, do 2 queries, first one to check if it already exists and the 2nd query to do the insert if the 1st found zero matches.

Method 2, use `insert ignore`  syntax, so duplicate inserts silently fail.

Method 3, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax to update columns of a entry that would have been inserted if it didn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just give validation it's simple and easy for checking already exists user / email in database

```
[
'field' => 'username',
'label' => 'User Name',
'rules' =>'trim|required|is_unique[login.username],
                        'errors' =>array('is_unique' => 'The %s is already  taken')
```

]

Here, `is_unique[login.username]` where login is table name and username is column which directlt see in database and check for unique value

for more go to [CI](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)